# References about continuity and differentiability in two and three dimensional

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, reference-request

I am trying to understand the Limits, continuity and differentiability, the gradient, the jacobian, extremals... for the case of function defined from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ or ($\mathbb{R}^2$)
but I found some books they give the definition and a little concrete example and goes for theoretical things

I need books  which gives a lot of example in each step and many exercises to understand well the whole subject and having a clear picture
Thank you

Comment: It would help if you could list the books you found that were not acceptable. Otherwise, you may be wasting your potential answerers time when they list books you don't like.

Comment: Thanks @LeeMosher I read books in french like this one https://www.amazon.com/Alg%C3%A8bre-Math%C3%A9matiques-pour-MP/dp/2729850147 and this one https://books.google.co.ma/books?id=C7jZc5TcFb4C&dq=cours+et+exercice+de+calcule+differentielle&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjuvfDQz5PrAhX6A2MBHcz4CLoQ6AEwAXoECAMQAg

Comment: @LeeMosher and the goal of this is to go to the courses of Differential geometry with a very nice knowledge